# Getting a hexadecimal number into a program via the command line

Tags: c, base-conversion, strtol

I can do this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  unsigned char cTest = 0xff;
  return 0;
}
```

But what's the right way to get a hexadecimal number into the program via the command line?

`unsigned char cTest = argv[1];`

doesn't do the trick. That produces a *initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast* warning.

Comment: Command line arguments are **always** strings. Some platforms may make them Unicode, in which case a simple `strtol` will not work.

Comment: @dirkgently: in which case `mbstol` or whatever the multibyte or wide char (or TCHAR) variants would cover that? (I also doubt this is a key concern given the nature of the question

Comment: @dirkgently: in that case, is the second parameter of `main()` not of type `char **`?  That can't be standards-compliant.

Comment: @Alok: They could still be multi-byte in which case mbstoul would be best, but that's far too fancy in the context of the question methinks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the type of `main` indicates, arguments from the command line are strings and will require conversion to different representations.

Converting a single hexadecimal command-line argument to decimal looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%ld\n", strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16));

  return 0;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./hex ff
255
```

Using `strtol` and changing the final argument from 16 to 0 as in

```
printf("%ld\n", strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0));
```

makes the program accept decimal, hexadecimal (indicated by leading `0x`, and octal (indicated by leading `0`) values:

```
$ ./num 0x70
112
$ ./num 070
56
$ ./num 70
70
```

Using the bash command shell, take advantage of [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) to have the shell perform the conversion, and then your program just prints the values from the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    unsigned char value = argv[i][0];
    if (strlen(argv[i]) > 1)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: '%s' is longer than one byte\n", argv[0], argv[i]);

    printf(i + 1 < argc ? "%u " : "%u\n", value);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Bash supports many formats of the form `$'...'`, but `$'\xHH'` appears to be the closest match to your question. For example:

```
$ ./print-byte $'\xFF' $'\x20' $'\x32'
255 32 50
```

Maybe you pack the values from the command line into a string and print it.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  if (argc > 1) {
    char *s = malloc(argc);
    if (!s) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: malloc: %s\n", argv[0], strerror(errno));
      return 1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
      s[i - 1] = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 16) & 0xff;

    s[argc - 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In action:

```
$ ./pack-string 48 65 6c 6c 6f 21
Hello!
```

All of the above is reinventing wheels that bash and the operating system already provide for you.

```
$ echo $'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x21'
Hello!
```

The `echo` program prints its command-line arguments on the standard output, which you can think of as a `for` loop over the arguments and a `printf` for each.

If you have another program that performs the decoding for you, use [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution) that replaces a command surrounded by backticks or `$()` with its output. See examples below, which again use `echo` as a placeholder.

```
$ echo $(perl -e 'print "\x50\x65\x72\x6c"')
Perl
$ echo `python -c 'print "\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"'`
Python
```

Answer (score 18):

I think some people arriving here might just be looking for:

```
$ ./prog `python -c 'print "\x41\x42\x43"'`
$ ./prog `perl -e 'print "\x41\x42\x43"'`
$ ./prog `ruby -e 'print "\x41\x42\x43"'`
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) which would walk through the characters in the string and convert them, taking into account the radix (16 in this context) that you pass in:-

```
char *terminatedAt;
if (argc != 2)
    return 1;

unsigned long value = strtoul( argv[1], &terminatedAt, 16);

if (*terminatedAt != '\0')
    return 2;

if (value > UCHAR_MAX)
    return 3;

unsigned char byte = (unsigned char)value;
printf( "value entered was: %d", byte);
```

As covered in the other examples, there are shorter ways, but none of them allow you to cleanly error check the processing (what happens if someone passes `FFF` and you've only got an `unsiged char` to put it into?

e.g. with `sscanf`:

```
int val;
sscanf(argv[1], &val)
printf("%d\n", val);
```

Comment: `UCHAR_MAX` may be greater than `LONG_MAX`, so you should use `strtoul()`, and `value > 255` should be `value > UCHAR_MAX`.  Finally, `static_cast` is C++; here you don't need a cast because of implicit conversion rules.

Comment: Ta, I had a `cout` in it in the intial version :P I considered using u initially but thought it would complicate matters too much given that the questioner is mainly looking to understand a concept that isnt immediately obvious to them.

Comment: I agree that sometimes one has to make things not-entirely-pedantically-correct for beginners, but in this case I think the pedantry isn't too hard, even for a beginner.  It will prevent many people from assuming that `UCHAR_MAX == 255` or `LONG_MAX > UCHAR_MAX`, etc.  Thanks for the edit and a good answer!

Comment: @Alok: Always happy to be pedantic, thanks! I think the cast is good here as it explains what's happening to a reader and will avoid warnings about the shortening conversion shoudl they be switched on. I'll leave out mbs concerns (and wchar_t concerns as the question ruled them out). Over and out!

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned char cTest = argv[1];
```

is wrong, because `argv[1]` is of type `char *`.  If `argv[1]` contains something like `"0xff"` and you want to assign the integer value corresponding to that to an `unsigned char`, the easiest way would be probably to use `strtoul()` to first convert it to an `unsigned long`, and then check to see if the converted value is less than or equal to `UCHAR_MAX`.  If yes, you can just assign to `cTest`.

`strtoul()`'s third parameter is a base, which can be 0 to denote C-style number parsing (octal and hexadecimal literals are allowed).  If you only want to allow base 16, pass that as the third argument to `strtoul()`.  If you want to allow any base (so you can parse `0xff`, `0377`, `255`, etc.), use 0.

`UCHAR_MAX` is defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: +1 good explanation, taking in the reasoning behind most of the points I'm trying to show in the code

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to do this kind of thing in C is with [scanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/). It's exactly the inverse of printf(), reading the given format *out* of the file (or terminal) and into the variables you list, rather than writing them into it.

In your case, you'd use `sscanf` as you've already got it in a string rather than a stream.

Answer (score -3):

`atoi`, `atol`, `strtoi`, `strtol`

all in `stdlib.h`

Comment: All pointed out 3 mins before (the see also of the linked man page) but not helping the questioner understand why its necessary or giving a sample. When a post isnt adding, it's good to delete it to keep it DRY